# How to sort an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array, each of whose elements is a hash with three key/value pairs:

```
:phone => "2130001111", :zip => "12345", :city => "sometown"
```

I'd like to sort the data by `zip` so all the `phone`s in the same area are together. Does Ruby have an easy way to do that? Can `will_paginate` paginate data in an array?

Comment: If you are generating the array, rather than it being a given, consider making it a hash instead, with elements (for example) `[city,zip]=>phone` or `city=>{zip1=>[<phones>], zip2=>...}`.

Answer (score 431, accepted):

Simples:

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:zip] }
```

**Note:**

When using `sort_by` you need to assign the result to a new variable: `array_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.sort_by{}` otherwise you can use the "bang" method to modify in place: `array_of_hashes.sort_by!{}`

Comment: When using `sort_by` you need to assign the result to a new variable: `array_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.sort_by{}` otherwise you can use the "bang" method to modify in place: `array_of_hashes.sort_by!{}`

Comment: Even shorter: `array_of_hashes.sort_by(&:zip)`

Comment: @Etienne: That's a shortcut for `.sort_by { |hsh| hsh.zip }` and so it'll only work if `.zip` is defined as a method on each Hash. By default hashes don't expose their keys as methods, so I guess you've probably got something else going on there.

Comment: Note the bang: `array_of_hashes.sort_by!(&:zip)`

Comment: @Gareth : In case of ActiveRecords, `.zip` and `[:zip]` both will work. ActiveRecords have both style defined.

Comment: @AtulVaibhav You're right, but that's nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 19):

```
sorted = dataarray.sort {|a,b| a[:zip] <=> b[:zip]}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the bang to modify in place the array:

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by!(&:zip)
```

Or re-assign it:

```
array_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.sort_by(&:zip)
```

**Note that sort_by method will sort by ascending order.**

If you need to sort with descending order you could do something like this:

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by!(&:zip).reverse!
```

or

```
array_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.sort_by(&:zip).reverse
```

Comment: The notation `&:` is a shortcut for `method`, not `attribute`! You are presuming that the Hash has methods reflecting attributes..

Comment: Thanks for the `reverse` method :p

Answer (score 5):

If you have *Nested Hash* (Hash inside a hash format) as Array elements (a structure like the following) and want to sort it by key (date here)

```
data =  [
    {
        "2018-11-13": {
            "avg_score": 4,
            "avg_duration": 29.24
        }
    },
    {
         "2017-03-13": {
            "avg_score": 4,
            "avg_duration": 40.24
        }
    },
    {
         "2018-03-13": {
            "avg_score": 4,
            "avg_duration": 39.24
        }
    }
]
```

Use Array 'sort_by' method as

```
data.sort_by { |element| element.keys.first }
```

Comment: This only works if you "parent" hashes only have a single key (the dates, in this case), because the ordering of `.keys` is not deterministic in some versions of ruby.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to paginate for data in array you should **require 'will_paginate/array'** in your controller