# There is error in sorting code which does not involve any callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app I'm creating an array like so:

```
@messages.each do |message|
  @list << {
    :id => message.id,
    :title => message.title,
    :time_ago => message.replies.first.created_at
  }
end
```

After making this array I would like to then sort it by time_ago ASC order, is that possible?

and is there any way in which i can change the order i between, i mea any callbacks available for this. Please suggest.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483889/in-ruby-how-sort-an-array-of-hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_array = @list.sort {|a,b| a[:time_ago] <=> b[:time_ago]}
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
@list.sort_by {|hash| hash[:time_ago]}
```

This will not alter the original array, so you'll need to assign it to some variable. If you want to sort it in place, use banged version `sort_by!` instead.

Just a note: There is a potential N+1 problem in your code, as your loop may execute an extra SQL query on each repetition. So remember to call `@messages.includes(:replies)` before looping. Also there might be much faster solution with a proper SQL query. However you need to specify why you want time_age to be the first value for messages in the database - could it be that you want the earliest message instead?

Comment: setting `time_ago` to a datetime value seems wrong to me.  It's like saying "This was posted 21/02/2014 days ago".