# Ruby - Sort by array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have this array of hashes:

```
@fournisseurs = [
{ id: 10592,
  nom: 'Carrossier Procolor Armand-Paris (Garage Michel Tondreau)',
  distance: '3.9 km',
  dispos: nil
},
{ id: 10463,
  nom: 'Carrossier Procolor Grand Beauport(Garage Michel Tondreau)',
  distance: '3.8 km',
  dispos: nil
}, 
{ id: 10594,
  nom: 'Honda Charlesbourg',
  distance: '5.2 km',
  dispos: nil
}, 
{ id: 10508,
  nom: 'Carrossier ProColor Charlesbourg',
  distance: '15.5 km',
  dispos: nil
}]
```

And I would like to sort it by distance. I tried `@fournisseurs.sort_by! { |fournisseur| fournisseur[:distance]}`, but it doesn't sort my array of hashes. I read that `sort_by!`was unstable. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am tempted to [close it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483889/how-to-sort-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of hashes in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483889/how-to-sort-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby)

Comment: @JosephCho I checked this post, and it didn't help me cause I did the same and it doesn't sort my array of hashes...

Comment: @Stefan I don't get a error message, but it doesn't sort my array of hashes.

Comment: @NoémieHarvey thanks for the edit and the clarification. Unfortunately, that hash is invalid and would result in a `SyntaxError`. For example, it should be `:id => ...` or `"id" => ...` – same for the values. Without a working hash, it's unclear what's causing the problem.

Comment: Copy and paste just one of your hashes into `irb`, I got lots of informative errors when I did so.  Your hash definitions aren't valid.

Comment: "unstable" does not mean it doesn't work - it means that when 2 distances happen to be the same, then the order of the 2 is not guaranteed to be maintained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that each distance is given as a string, you need to convert it to a float to effectively sort by distance.

```
@fournisseurs = [
{ id: 10592,
  nom: 'Carrossier Procolor Armand-Paris (Garage Michel Tondreau)',
  distance: '3.9 km',
  dispos: nil
},
{ id: 10463,
  nom: 'Carrossier Procolor Grand Beauport(Garage Michel Tondreau)',
  distance: '3.8 km',
  dispos: nil
}, 
{ id: 10594,
  nom: 'Honda Charlesbourg',
  distance: '5.2 km',
  dispos: nil
}, 
{ id: 10508,
  nom: 'Carrossier ProColor Charlesbourg',
  distance: '15.5 km',
  dispos: nil
}]


@fournisseurs.sort_by! { |f| f[:distance].to_f}


puts @fournisseurs.inspect
```

Comment: You don't have to `split` – `to_f` ignores tailing characters, i.e. `'3.9 km'.to_f` returns `3.9`.

Comment: @Stefan, fixed.

Comment: _"@Stefan, fixed. – Stefan"_ – that has a nice schizophrenic touch 