# Replacing a number with the respective number of "-" 's

Tags: ruby

I am working with this:

> Write a program that draws bar graphs.  It should:
>
> - Ask the user for a list of numbers.  The user enters them
>     separated by commas, e.g.: `10,4,2,7,5,1`.
> - Print a horizontal bar graph of the numbers in order.
> - Bar should be made up of `-`s.
> - Example output from running the program:
>
>   ```
>   Enter some numbers to graph
>   10,4,2,7,5,1
>   ----------
>   ----
>   --
>   -------
>   -----
>   -
>   ```

This is what I have:

```
puts "Insert a list of numbers, separated by commas :"
answer = gets.chomp
answer.split(",").each do |x|
  puts "-"
end
```

I'm stuck at printing `-` n number of times. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you got stuck? Did you manage to print the message? Could you read the input? Do you know how to extract the numbers from the input? Have you trouble printing `-` _n_ times? What is it, specifically?

Comment: Basically at least show you've started and tried something before asking for help :P

Comment: `puts [10,4,2,7,5,1].map { |x| '-' * x }.join("\n")`

Comment: puts "Insert a list of numbers, separated by commas :"
answer = gets.chomp
answer.split(",").each do |x|
    puts "-"
end
Sorry guys, I'm fairly new to coding, I'm stuck at printing "-" n number of times basically.

Comment: @DanGroze please edit your question next time, comments are easily overlooked (and code without formatting is hard to read).

Comment: Thanks for all your help and tips, I'm new to all this, apologies :)

Answer (score 7):

Ruby has a great feature where you can "multiply" a string by a number.

```
puts "Enter some numbers to graph"
input = gets
numbers = input.split(",")

numbers.each do |number|
  puts "-" * number.to_i
end
```

A more concise version would be:

```
print "enter numbers: "
gets.split(",").each {|n| puts '-'*n.to_i }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stefan! I wasn't that far off from solving it, I see!

Comment: @DanGroze don't forget to accept Stefan's answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @DanGroze: yeah, you could have used `print` in a [nested] loop.

Comment: mudasobwa edition: `puts str.split(",").map(&:to_i).map(&'-'.method(:*))`

Comment: @Stefan (user id 477037) The author of this answer is a different person from you? A bit confusing. Hahaha. After writing the sentence above, I realized that it is not certain which Stefan my `@Stefan` will mention.

Comment: @sawa this is so weird, isn't it? Happened before, although that might have been yet another Stefan ;-) BTW, I got the mention, maybe both of us did.

Comment: @sawa, it's happened to us before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701188/ruby-sort-by-array-of-hashes/50701499#comment88413015_50701499

Comment: @Stefan OMG it's you again! ^_^